How to log the number of open file handles in a Docker container hosting a Python application?
I have built a Python webscraper application using Selenium.
The Python Selenium library communicates with a (headless) chrome browser instance.
I believe that file handle resources are being leaked by Selenium or the chrome browser. The reason I believe this to be the case is because the application eventually crashes after long periods of time.

When not running in a Docker container, the application will crash every few days
When running inside a Docker container, the application crashes much more regularly. Every few hours
When the Docker container starts, a warning about ulimit is emitted

These things seem to point to resource leaks.
The exact error message when the application crashes is:
Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
  (Session info: chrome-headless-shell=127.0.6533.72)

I am not really sure how to diagnose this just yet, but one potential idea which came to mind would be to log or monitor the number of open files.
I haven't found a good way of doing this.
Currently, I tried this:

docker exec -it container_name bash
sudo apt update && sudo apt install lsof
watch --interval 10 'lsof | wc -l

This sort of works. The number of open files reported appears to be jumping around all over the place. I have seen values from as low as 200 to as high as 12000. There doesn't appear to be any obvious trend, at least not as far as I can tell from watching the output from time to time during the last hour.
Additionally, if the application crashes the Docker container will close, and this session will be killed, meaning there is no way for me to know what the last observed value is.
